# juju status can't resolve hostname

Tags: cloud, juju, orchestra

I'm trying to install a private cloud with Ubuntu Server 11.10. I've successfully installed orchestra by following the below tutorial:

- http://cloud.ubuntu.com/2011/09/oneiric-server-deploy-server-fleets-p1/

Then I've followed this tutorial to install and configure juju:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure

The juju bootstrap command finished successful and by booting the machine it installed ubuntu server. When I then try to run the juju status command I get the following error:

```
juju -v status
2012-04-07 19:52:54,385 DEBUG Initializing juju status runtime
2012-04-07 19:52:54,408 INFO Connecting to environment.
2012-04-07 19:52:54,409 DEBUG Spawning SSH process with remote_user="ubuntu" remote_host="JujuBootstrap" remote_port="2181" local_port="35589".
Cannot connect to machine MTMzMzgyMDY2OS44MjE5MzAzNzkuMzA0Mzg (perhaps still initializing): could not connect before timeout after 1 retries
2012-04-07 19:53:24,520 ERROR Cannot connect to machine MTMzMzgyMDY2OS44MjE5MzAzNzkuMzA0Mzg (perhaps still initializing): could not connect before timeout after 1 retries
```

I guess there is a problem with resolving the hostname I've set for the system in Orchestra. I can ping the machine correctly by using its IP address.

Is there a way to configure juju to use IP addresses instead of hostnames? Or is this rather a bug in Orchestra/Juju and the default DHCP configuration set during the installation of Orchestra?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, juju and orchestra need DNS to work and agree between clients and the juju managed machines. You can "fake it" by editing the `/etc/hosts` files on all the machines to be correct if you haven't set up orchestra's built in dnsmasq server to do DHCP and DNS, which is the simplest method, but requires a dedicated network for your managed machines (since it would fight with an existing DHCP server).